# No auto-update after moving ClickOnce manifest to a different server

Tags: clickonce, manifest

I have changed the deployment provider in the manifest of my WinForms application. It is a signed manifest. I also incremented the pubish version of the manifest.

However it seems that I have to uninstall the application on the client and re-install it, because it doesn't pick up the update automatically like normally.

Is this something that you would have expected or is this behavior incorrect?

As it turned out only a reinstall was needed, not an uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you've changed the published location of your application, yet your customers that user your ClickOnce application are not getting the update?

If the above statement is true and you are using the .Net 2.0 or 3.0 framework, then you have no choice but to uninstall and reinstall the application.

This has been a major headache for me in the past, so I wrote a simple API that you can add to your project that simplifies and helps automate the update process.  For the API to work, you must add it to your application and publish an update to your original server.  Every time your application starts, the application checks a config file on your server to see if there is an update that should be applied from another installation location.  If there is, it unistalls the current version and installs the new one.

For more information, check out [this](http://blog.richardhartness.com/2011_03_01_archive.html) blog post, or download the API from the [projects home page](http://code.google.com/p/clickonce-application-reinstaller-api/).